# why is livewire component not updating columns in the database

Tags: data-binding, sql-update, laravel-livewire, laravel-10

I have created a livewire component in order to update the marks of students in a particular course when the admin inputs their marks in order to update the ca*mark and exammark columns* in my pivot table called course_students, the problem i am facing is that when i submit the inputed marks, my session shows "marks updated successfully but", but when i check and refresh my database, i see that the columns still have their default values as 0. Please I need help!

This is what I have done: the first block of code below is the updateMarks function in my livewire component class, its purpose is to update the ca_marks, exam_marks of a particular student in particular course, i also use **DB::getQueryLog()** to show all the sql queries in my updateMarks function.

```
public function updateMarks()
    {
        // enable the query log for the default connection
        DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();

        // enable the query log
        DB::enableQueryLog();

        // find the course_student record by its id
        $course_student = course_student::find($this->course);

        // update the marks using the update method
        $updated = $course_student->update([
            'ca_marks' => $this->ca_mark,
            'exam_marks' => $this->exam_mark,
        ]);

        // check if the update was successful
        if ($updated) {
            // flash a success message
            session()->flash('message', 'Marks updated successfully.');
        } else {
            // flash an error message
            session()->flash('error', 'Something went wrong.');
        }

        // get the query log
        $queryLog = DB::getQueryLog();

        // dump the query log
        dd($queryLog);
    }
```

This is the result of the $queryLog, which shows all the queries and bindings in my updateMarks function, including the values of ca_*mark and exam*_mark that are being submitted

```
array:2 [▼ // app\Livewire\StudentMarks.php:167
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `course_students` where `course_students`.`id` = ? limit 1"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => 11
    ]
    "time" => 0.77
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "update `course_students` set `ca_marks` = ?, `exam_marks` = ?, `course_students`.`updated_at` = ? where `id` = ?"
    "bindings" => array:4 [▼
      0 => "5"
      1 => "7"
      2 => "2023-12-12 08:54:16"
      3 => 11
    ]
    "time" => 40.8
  ]
]
```

The code below has the button that triggers the updateMarks function in my class and  the loop of all the students in a particular selected course along side their ca*marks and exam*Marks in inputs from the database

```
@if (session()->has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('message') }}
    </div>
@endif
<button wire:click="updateMarks">Update</button>

<tbody>
@isset($course_students)
@foreach($course_students as $course_student)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $course_student->student->matricule }}</td>
        <td>{{ $course_student->student->name }}</td>
        <td>
            <input placeholder="{{ $course_student->ca_marks }}" type="number" wire:model="ca_mark">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input placeholder="{{ $course_student->exam_marks }}" type="number" wire:model="exam_mark">
        </td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
@endisset
</tbody>
```

Comment: How can the *updateMarks()* function understand which *$course_students* row must be updated?